# Is it possible to wipe all of the NSUserDefaults set in your app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsuserdefaults

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSUserDefaults reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358737/nsuserdefaults-reset)

Is it possible to wipe all of the NSUserDefaults set in your app? Such as if the user hits a "Reset" button? Thanks!

Comment: Exact duplicate of [NSUserDefaults reset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358737/nsuserdefaults-reset) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613951/force-reset-nsuserdefault-on-iphone-app-upgrade

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults]